# Jenkins boostrap in separate job than build job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins pipeline job which bootstraps itself. The idea here is to self test changes, including changes to the jenkins pipeline groovy scripts, which are stored in git.

I was wondering how to bootstrap in a separate job than the build job. So for example, if I have a job called *"build_linux"*, currently Jenkins will create a *"workspace/build_linux"* folder, and everything inside there will both bootstrap and build within there.

The issue here is that my build_repository.git is very large, and I don't want to check it out twice at the bootstrap stage and the build stage. However, if I don't check them both out in both stages, git (In actuality I'm repo syncing a manifest with both git repositories from the Google 'repo' scripts) complain that there's code in there which shouldn't be, and either fails or will try to clean it up (which is inefficient).

Ideally I'd just have both *"workspace/bootstrap/"* and *"workspace/linux_build/"* job folders.

For example, my pipeline looks like this:

**bootstrap.gvy:**

```
--> **entry point from my jenkins config**

stage('Bootstrap') {
    node("$BOOTSTRAP_NODE") {
        git checkout bootstrap_repository.git
        git checkout build_repository.git // I don't want to do this here
        pipeline = load "build/build.gvy"
    }

    pipeline.main(env.JOB_NAME) // which in this case is "build_linux"
}
```

**build/build.gvy:**

```
int main(String jobName) {
    switch (jobname) {
        case "build_linux":
        doBuildLiunx()
        break
    }
}

def doBuildLinux() {
    stage("Build") {
        node("$BUILD_NODE") {
             git checkout bootstrap_repository.git // I don't want to do this here
             git checkout build_repository.git
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions for how to accomplish this? Perhaps I should use a different workspace for bootstrapping?

Thanks

Comment: "it complains there's code in there that shouldn't be there"... we have that problem with integration test artifacts.   Perhaps you could do what we did, which is add to your .gitignore so it ignores any files you create during the first step?

Comment: I'd have to add everything in my gitignore then, as the folders are mutually exclusive :) It also seems like a waste, because it'd have to completely clean up and checkout completely separate repositories.